# How can I iterate through JSON objects even there is error using Scala Jackson

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

Currently, jackson is rejecting the whole JSON when there is blank property value.

I want to use com.fasterxml.jackson.* to parse JSON code.

As you see below input JSON, name attribute is blank some of the elements.

Hense iterate through JSON objects will ignore by Jackson.

hence there will be 2 elements formed as part of the output.

I am using below code but no luck

```
 def readJsonString[T](content: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory().enable(Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS)) with ScalaObjectMapper
    objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, false)
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
    objectMapper.readValue(content)

  }
```

//Existing Json that I want to use as input where some attribute has blank value

```
[
                {
                    "name": "Invalid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "", "country": ["USA"] } ]
                    
                },
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "ruleType": "validation_2",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "place": ["USA"] } ]
                    
                },
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": []
                    
                }
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_2",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "place": ["USA"] } ]
                    
                },
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "place": ["France"] } ]
                    
                }
        ]
```

//New Json that will created from above which has proper name attribute value

```
[
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "country": ["USA"] } ]
                    
                }
                 
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "place": ["France"] } ]
                    
                }
        ]
```

Comment: the description is not enough to understand the problem for answerers. Please include what you tried and where you are stuck

Comment: I have added the proper description.Here I want to prepare a new json from existing json by validating its attribute,For example New Json that will created from given input which has proper name attribute value.

Comment: You reading the JSON from a file system?
What is the desired output location of the output?
On what criteria you mark the `name` key as valid? It'd also be helpful is you can share the code you tried.

Comment: You can put whole json in a file and produce another json as string

Comment: I think what you're looking to do, is to put those variable's / keys as Options and that way it will be fine?

Comment: I want to read each element and which is not valid i will skip it

Comment: This has been resolved myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution that would work using jackson:

Case classes to map your json to:

```
  case class NamePlace(Name: String, country: Seq[String])
  case class NameRuleTypeInputs(name: String, ruleType: String, inputs: Seq[NamePlace])
```

Custom serializer to include field validations before serializing:

```
  class NameRuleTypeInputsSerializer(defaultSerializer: JsonSerializer[Object]) extends JsonSerializer[NameRuleTypeInputs] {
    override def serialize(value: NameRuleTypeInputs, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider): Unit = {
      if (isValid(value)) {
        defaultSerializer.serialize(value, gen, serializers)
      }
    }

    private def isValid(value: NameRuleTypeInputs) = {
      !Option(value.name).getOrElse("").isEmpty &&
        Option(value.inputs).getOrElse(Seq.empty).nonEmpty &&
        !value.inputs.exists(i => Option(i.Name).getOrElse("").isEmpty)
    }
  }
```

Updated your objectMapper to include the custom serializer:

```
  val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory().enable(Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS)) with ScalaObjectMapper
  objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, false)
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
  objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule(){
    override def setupModule(context: Module.SetupContext): Unit = {
      super.setupModule(context)
      context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
        override def modifySerializer(config: SerializationConfig, beanDesc: BeanDescription, serializer: JsonSerializer[_]): JsonSerializer[_] = {
          if(classOf[NameRuleTypeInputs] isAssignableFrom beanDesc.getBeanClass) {
            new NameRuleTypeInputsSerializer(serializer.asInstanceOf[JsonSerializer[Object]])
          } else {
            serializer
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

Methods to read/write json:

```
  def readJsonString[T](content: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    objectMapper.readValue(content)
  }

  def writeJsonString(nameRuleTypeInputsList: Seq[NameRuleTypeInputs]): String = {
    // Using pretty printer for readability
    objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(nameRuleTypeInputsList)
  }
```

A small test:

```
val testJson =
    """
        [
                {
                    "name": "Invalid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "", "country": ["USA"] } ]

                },
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "ruleType": "validation_2",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "country": ["USA"] } ]

                },
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": []

                },
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_2",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "country": ["USA"] } ]

                },
                {
                    "name": "Valid",
                    "ruleType": "validation_1",
                    "inputs": [ { "Name": "Test", "country": ["France"] } ]

                }
        ]
    """.stripMargin
```

```
  val namedRuleTypeInputs: Seq[NameRuleTypeInputs] = readJsonString[Seq[NameRuleTypeInputs]](testJson)

  println(writeJsonString(namedRuleTypeInputs))
```

Output:

```
[ {
  "name" : "Valid",
  "ruleType" : "validation_2",
  "inputs" : [ {
    "Name" : "Test",
    "country" : [ "USA" ]
  } ]
}, {
  "name" : "Valid",
  "ruleType" : "validation_1",
  "inputs" : [ {
    "Name" : "Test",
    "country" : [ "France" ]
  } ]
} ]
```

Useful Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Comment: This is what I am looking for.I appreciate your work